# How to use compiled gettext .mo files without the gettext module?

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I'm trying to find a way to use `gettext` and friends without depending on the official [gettext module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), which I've found to not be installed everywhere and sometimes yields different results depending on the OS and server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forked [`PHP-gettext`](https://github.com/SimpleUpdates/PHP-Gettext) (not the GNU GPL one) and modifying it to work as a transparent drop in. It creates a very simple one line fix for a missing gettext module.

```
require( "PHP-Gettext/Autoload.php" );
```

Answer (score 3):

I just make a library which can auto load the po file, change languages and translate all text between {t} and {/t} in the view, I posted here in case some one want to use it instead calling the gettext function in the view:

http://www.chuongduong.net/page/15/codeigniter-gettext-with-smarty-or-parser-template-without-php-code-in-view.html

The view code might be:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{blog_title}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>{blog_heading}</h3>
{blog_entries}

<h5>{t}Title is{/t}  {title}</h5>

<p>{t 1="<b>" 2="</b>"}Click here %1to see%2 me{/t}{body}</p>

<p>{t 1="{id}" 2="author"}The id is: %1 wrote by %2{/t}</p>

<p>{t 1="<a href=\"link here\">" 2="</a>"}Please lick on me%2{/t}</p>

{/blog_entries}

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few userland php implementations of the gettext functions.

- One is [gettext.php](http://upgradephp.berlios.de/) (I wrote that, PD, but not very well tested)
- And the other one [php-gettext](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/php-gettext/) (GNU GPL, quite widespread)
- The Zend Framework also provides an [adapter for gettext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html). Not sure if it relies on the native PHP functions; but it might very well come with its own reimplementation.

Comment: I'm getting an error from upgrade.php download link: `unicorn Could Not Connect to Database:`

Comment: Oh, interesting; BerliOS is down. Here's an alternative link: http://include-once.org/upgradephp-17.tgz

Comment: Unicorn could not connect to database?

Comment: @Pekka: Well it's apparently not cloud-based. It runs on good old Unicorn blood. Seeminlgy that's out, so that explains the downtime (TWO WEEKS! time for github)